# Entering Germany while having a visa issued by a different country?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports

I believe this question was asked before but I think my case is a little bit different. My father works at the French embassy and so I have a Schengen visa issued for me from the French Embassy. Now I never visited France before and I plan to go Germany next week. Is it ok to go straight to Berlin with a visa issued by France. Again I will not be landing or visitng France at all.

Comment: Technically the Schengen visa should be issued by the 'main' country that you are visiting.

Comment: What typo of visa do you have?

Comment: Multiple entry visa ( Tourist)

Comment: Then you are fine

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to go to any Schengen country with a valid Schengen visa and correct type, regardless of the country issued the visa.